# Recover Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 soft bricked with bootloader locked

Tags: adb, fastboot, data-recovery, unbricking, xiaomi

This night I went to sleep, left my Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 charging, and when woke up the phone was off, with the white light on. When tried to turn on, it stays in the Mi.com logo. So I think its a soft brick.

For adittional info: Lately the phone was slow, with storage at high.

Looking for answerings, I went through some tutorials. But I would like to maintain my data. The usual stuff as photos, and some info that is into a note app.

Saying that, the things arent looking well, since I never changed my OS and anything, so its probably with its bootloader locked.

I found this portuguese tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syaAs7vrOpo

Basically it says where to download image and some files. Install adb. Enter the fastboot mode in the phone (I was able to do that) and some commands to execute in cmd. They are:

```
fastboot flash xbl xbl.elf
fastboot flash xblbak xbl.elf
fastboot flash tz tz.mbn
fastboot flash tzbak tz.mbn
fastboot flash rpm rpm.mbn
fastboot flash rpmbak rpm.mbn
fastboot flash hyp hyp.mbn
fastboot flash hypbak hyp.mbn
fastboot flash pmic pmic.elf
fastboot flash pmicbak pmic.elf
fastboot flash keymaster keymaster.mbn
fastboot flash keymasterbak keymaster.mbn
fastboot flash cmnlib cmnlib.mbn
fastboot flash cmnlibbak cmnlib.mbn
fastboot flash cmnlib64 cmnlib64.mbn
fastboot flash cmnlib64bak cmnlib64.mbn
fastboot flash mdtpsecapp mdtpsecapp.mbn
fastboot flash mdtpsecappbak mdtpsecapp.mbn
fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin
fastboot flash dsp dspso.bin
fastboot flash bluetooth BTFM.bin
fastboot flash storsec storsec.mbn
fastboot flash storsecbak storsec.mbn
fastboot flash devcfg devcfg.mbn
fastboot flash devcfgbak devcfg.mbn
fastboot flash abl abl.elf
fastboot flash ablbak abl.elf
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash vendor vendor.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
fastboot flash mdtp mdtp.img
fastboot flash cache cache.img
fastboot flash splash splash.img
fastboot erase ddr
fastboot erase misc
fastboot erase apdp
fastboot erase msadp
fastboot flash cust cust.img
rem fastboot erase config
fastboot reboot
```

Looking at these commands, it looks like it will wipe the data, with the command:

fastboot flash userdata userdata.img

So, if I remove this command, and try to execute the rest, it should flash the rom and dont wipe the data?
Or it can cause some more problems to the phone?

What would you guys suggest to me to get out of this situation, preferencly with my data?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually fastboot requires an unlocked bootloader even if you want to flash the original stock image. Only from within recovery you can write firmware using `adb sideload`. But as your problem is most likely located on the user data partition (just a guess: system had run out of space) this might also not help you.

Comment: I dont think ADB is working.

When I type:

`adb devices`

Just shows:

`List of devices attached`

Without any device listed.

But if I type:

`fastboot devices`
`fastboot getvar all`

I was able to see some information.

One call my attention:

`(bootloader) unlocked: yes`

So what could I do from now? Theres some move to preserve or recovery the data?

Comment: If the bootloader is unlocked you can try to flash the other partitions. You will see if it changes something.

Comment: After flashing, do not attempt to re-lock the bootloader. A side note, I've messed with multiple phones, but the Xiaomi is always a pain. I bricked my Redmi Note 4 (when I tried rooting for the first time) I'd suggest to get it unbricked by someone professional if you're new to this. Save it while it is in soft brick. Anyways, I am guess  you will not be able to save your data..